# JQuery signalr is working but polling is cycling on every 2 seconds

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

Found this article at

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526876/Adding-SignalR-to-an-ASP-NET-WebForms-Project

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

So I gave it a shot but it only showed "Logging Started" but no every 2 seconds cycling "Still running".  Not sure why is that.

[image]

// C#

```
namespace Web.ApiHubs
{
    [HubName("logHub")]
    public class LogHub : Hub
    {
        public static readonly Timer _timer = new Timer();

        static LogHub()
        {
            _timer.Interval = 2000;
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private static void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("LogHub");
            hubContext.Clients.All.logMessage(string.Format("{0} - Still running", DateTime.UtcNow));
        }
    }
}
```

// JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var logHubProxy = $.connection.logHub;

        logHubProxy.client.logMessage = function (msg) {
            $("#logUl").append("<li>" + msg + "</li>");
        };

        $.connection.hub.logging = true;

        //$.connection.hub.start();
        $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });
    });
});
```